# Sphinx query takes too much time

Tags: sphinx

I am making an index on a table with ~90 000 000 rows. Fulltext search must be done on a varchar field, called `email`. I also set `parent_id` as an attribute.

When I run queries to search emails that match words with small amount of hits, they are fired immediately:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE MATCH('diedsmiling');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       26 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show meta;
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| total         | 1           |
| total_found   | 1           |
| time          | 0.000       |
| keyword[0]    | diedsmiling |
| docs[0]       | 26          |
| hits[0]       | 26          |
+---------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Things get complicated when I am searching for emails that match words with a big amount of hits:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE MATCH('mail');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 33237994 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.21 sec)

mysql> show meta;
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| total         | 1        |
| total_found   | 1        |
| time          | 9.210    |
| keyword[0]    | mail     |
| docs[0]       | 33237994 |
| hits[0]       | 33253762 |
+---------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using `parent_id` attribute, doesn't give any profit:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE MATCH('mail') AND parent_id = 62003;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    21404 |
+----------+
1 row in set (8.66 sec)

mysql> show meta;
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| total         | 1        |
| total_found   | 1        |
| time          | 8.666    |
| keyword[0]    | mail     |
| docs[0]       | 33237994 |
| hits[0]       | 33253762 |
```

Here are my sphinx configs:

```
source src1
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = HOST
    sql_user        = USER
    sql_pass        = PASS
    sql_db          = DATABASE
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
             SELECT id, parent_id, email \
                FROM users

    sql_attr_uint   = parent_id     

}    

index test1
{       
    source          = src1
    path            = /var/lib/sphinx/test1

}
```

The query that I need to run looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH('mail') AND parent_id = 62003;
```

I need to get all emails that match a certain work and have a certain `parent_id`.

---

**My questions are:**
Is there a way to optimize the situation described above? Maybe there is a more convenient matching mode for such type of queries? If I migrate to a server with SSD disks will the performance growth be significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get count can just do

```
 Select id from index where match(...) limit 0 option ranker=none; show meta;
```

And get from total_found.

Will be much more efficient than count[*) which invokes group by.

Or even `call keywords('word','index',1);` if only single words.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the query that I need to run looks like: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH('mail') AND parent_id = 62003;`. I need to get all emails that match a certain work and have a certain `parent_id`.

Comment: So? The same idea should still work. Using `total_found` is more efficent than using COUNT(*)` - ranking or even the results themseves are not needed.

Comment: Although if performance is really an issue, then maybe using a field (rather than attribute) might be slightly quicker. It can use doclists to answer the query. `MATCH('mail @parent 62003')`

Comment: I'll try tomorrow. Thanks.